# Command-line arguments available to other functions?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

In C, is there any way to make command line arguments available to other functions without passing them as arguments to the functions?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: They're not any different than any other data. You can pass them or make them global (i.e. store the values in global variables).

Answer (score 1):

Some compilers provides global `_argc` and `_argv` variables for that exact purpose.  Or use platform-specific APIs, like `GetCommandLine()` and `CommandLineToArgvW()` on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

As DaoWen has said, the command-line arguments are just data, available in main().  So if you don't want to pass a command-line argument as a parameter to another function but you want it available in other functions, you could strcpy()/strncpy() the string into a global string.